# my class has no suitable copy constructor - depending if the argument of the constructor is const or not

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor

**Question:**

I am learning c++, and i created a class to represent complex numbers. I created a copy constructor with the format

```
complex(const complex &c);
```

and the program worked fine.

Then, i removed the const (so it became: `complex( complex &c);` ) and the program doesn't work. It gives me this error:

`"message": "class \"complex\" has no suitable copy constructor"`

and it refers to the add method. The add method is this:

```
complex complex::add(complex &c){
    return complex( re + c.re, im + c.im);
};
```

If i do not add this method (and methods that generally return a complex number that is created in the return line, like this:  `return complex (integer_variable_Re, integer_variable_Im)` ) the program works fine. When i add these kinds of methods, it throws me the error. I cannot understand why this doesn't work, as it should call the constructor that takes two integers and not the copy constructor.

**Specs:**
Ubuntu: 20.04Lts

IDE: VScode

Compliler: G++ 9.4

(it says somewhere this: `GNU C17 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) version 9.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu) compiled by GNU C version 9.4.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.22.1-GMP`, do not know if it it the compliler standard.)

**Whole error message:**
`[{      "resource": "/home/papaveneti/Documents/Programming/LearnCpp/complex_classStack.cpp",    "owner": "C/C++",    "code": "334",   "severity": 8,   "message": "class \"complex\" has no suitable copy constructor",     "source": "C/C++",   "startLineNumber": 48,   "startColumn": 12,   "endLineNumber": 48,     "endColumn": 19  }]`

**Whole program:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class complex {

public:
    complex (double r, double i); // constructor
    // only method that does not specify type
    
    //default constructor
    complex (); 

    //copy cosntructor
    complex( complex &c);

    // methods: 
    complex add(complex &c);
    void norm1();

private:
    // fields:
    double re, im; 
    double norm;
};

//constructor does not need to name a type
complex::complex(double r=0.0, double i=0.0){ // default values are 0
    re = r; im = i; 
    norm1();
};

complex::complex(){
    re=im=0;
}

complex::complex( complex &c){
    re=c.re;
    im=c.im;
}

void complex::norm1(){
    norm = sqrt(re*re + im*im);
};

complex complex::add(complex &c){
    return complex( re + c.re, im + c.im);
};

int main(){
    complex c1(3,4), c2(1,2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please incldue the complete error message

Comment: your whole program complies fine here : https://godbolt.org/z/1v8Kzhvzh.

Comment: Your main does not involve the add member.

Comment: Show the code that doesn't work instead of showing the one that does work.

Comment: You are stuck with a pre-C++17 compiler, aren't you? If so, please add the corresponding version tag, otherwise, the most up-to-date C++ standard is implied.

Comment: @Jason Liam I showed the program that doesn't work for me

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Error message as copied by Vscode:
`[{
 "resource": "/home/papaveneti/Documents/Programming/LearnCpp/complex_classStack.cpp",
 "owner": "C/C++",
 "code": "334",
 "severity": 8,
 "message": "class \"complex\" has no suitable copy constructor",
 "source": "C/C++",
 "startLineNumber": 48,
 "startColumn": 12,
 "endLineNumber": 48,
 "endColumn": 19
}]`

i am using ubuntu 20.04LTS and i use VScode. The gcc-- version gives me :
`gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0`

Comment: j6t asked for the compiler and C++ version. ubuntu is your OS and VSCode is your IDE. VSCode implies likely msvc but not sure. What compiler and what c++ standard are you using?

Comment: you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74150499/edit) the question to add missing information

Comment: The problem is not the construction of the complex object from the two `double`s but the copy, that is involved during the return mechanism.

Comment: Since C++17 returning a temporary object, does not involve a copy anymore due to mandatory copy elision. Thus your program compiles fine in C++17 onwards.

Comment: @MIKEPAPADAKIS You can use `C++17` to solve this error meanwhile.

Comment: @MIKEPAPADAKIS **The program is ill-formed**. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74150943/12002570) below for reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before C++17, the following line

```
return complex( re + c.re, im + c.im);
```

actually includes two object creations. First an unnamed temporary object is constructed using two `double` parameters. Then a copy of this object is made to where the return value is stored. This second copy is the reason for your compiler error. A copy constructor can only be used to copy a temporary object, if it is declared like this:

```
complex(const complex&);
```

If you omit the `const` qualifier, you cannot pass a temporary object.

With the introduction of [mandatory copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) in C++17, there is no copy (or move) involved in the line mentioned above. Thus your program compiles fine. Your compiler, which is rather old, does not use C++17 by default and so refuses to compile the program.

To solve your problem, you could either

- use a copy constructor which takes a `const` reference
- add a move constructor
- use C++17 (either by using a newer compiler version or by passing the `--std=c++17` command line option to your compiler

**Edit:**
You should also fix the problem that @Jason Liam mentions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74150943/17862371). As mentioned there, your program is ill-formed and should not compile even with the `const` constructor.

Comment: This is wrong because the program is actually **ill-formed**.

Comment: Even if you add the `const` to the parameter of the copy ctor, the program will still be ill-formed. See [demo c++14](https://godbolt.org/z/EGcbjoj7r) where clang rejects the program because it is ill-formed.

Comment: See also clang rejects even after adding const. [Program](https://godbolt.org/z/e41ovdf3x).

Comment: @JasonLiam You're correct, but that does not invalidate my answer. Even if you corrected the error that you mention in you answer, the program would fail to compile (at least for clang and gcc) before C++17 (see this [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d6689bGMr))

Comment: This worked for me. I had to do it in the terminal with the `--std=c++17`. I changed the definition of `complex::complex(double r, double)` as Liam said, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @MIKEPAPADAKIS The program is still invalid in C++17. The compiler you're using has a bug. I am submitting the bug report. See at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The program is **ill-formed** in all C++ versions and *gcc and msvc are wrong in [accepting](https://godbolt.org/z/dca5s8eeo) the code* because while defining the constructor `complex::complex(double r, double)` **outside the class** you're providing default arguments for both of the parameters which turns it into a default constructor. This is not allowed and [clang rejects it](https://godbolt.org/z/e41ovdf3x).

From [default arguments documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments):

> For a member function of a non-template class, the default arguments are allowed on the out-of-class definition, and are combined with the default arguments provided by the declaration inside the class body. **If these out-of-class defaults would turn a member function into a default constructor or copy/move (since C++11) constructor/assignment operator, the program is ill-formed**

(emphasis mine)

To solve this you have to make sure that you don't add these default arguments while implementing the ctor outside the class so that you avoid turning it into a default ctor. Additionally, if you're using C++11 or C++14 then you must add a low-level const to the parameter of the copy ctor as there was no mandatory copy elision prior to C++17.

---

Here is the gcc bug:

[GCC accepts ill-formed out of class definition program](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=107343)

Here is the msvc bug:

[MSVC accepts invalid program involving default arguments inside constructor](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-accepts-invalid-program-involving-d/10178713)

Comment: Is it ill-formed because i (could )have two default constructors. One that would give default values in `complex::complex(double r=0, double i=0)` and the default `complex::complex()` ?

Comment: @MIKEPAPADAKIS Yes exactly. See i've quoted the same reason in the middle of my answer saying: *"If these out-of-class defaults would turn a member function into a default constructor or copy/move (since C++11) constructor/assignment operator, the program is **ill-formed**"*. To solve this you have to make sure that you don't add these default arguments while implementing the ctor outside the class so that you avoid turning it into a default ctor.

Comment: There is also [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58194) and [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86255) bug report in GCC referring to the same issue. Apparently [this](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1344.html) change in the standard is just not yet implemented in GCC. Before that change, the program was not ill-formed, but just the usage of a default constructor that originates in such a way was ambiguous.

Comment: @JakobStark So it seems gcc hasn't implemented it yet even though it has been many years since cwg!